# Is there a documentation extractor/generator a-la pydoc for Tcl?

Tags: tcl, expect

Does Tcl has a local documentation extractor/generator tool one can use to quickly get information about a Tcl command or a command out of a Tcl package/module like expect?

Something like pydoc in the Python world?

I'm starting to use expect and would like to integrate such a tool to my editor so  I could quickly look up Tcl reference information.

For example, on a given snippet of Tcl code like:

```
package require Expect

spawn bash

exp_send "ls -l\n"

set accum {}
expect {
    -regexp {..*} {
        set accum "${accum}$expect_out(0,string)" 
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to request information about `package` or `exp_continue` or any Tcl keyword or library command.

So far I did not find anything describing such a tool in the Tcl wiki.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: The question is not just a generic request to find documentation,  but to ask if Tcl has a command like "help" that could be called by the users editor.

As far as I know, tclsh does not have a help command.   I work with a Tcl interface in Synopsys IC design tools, and that version of Tcl does have a help and a man command.

I don't know about expect.

Comment: @KenWhite I was not asking if this tool or that tool is better.  I am just trying to find if Tcl itself provides the capability of a "help" command.  I realize that asking for an opinion is not a valid request.  But was hoping that asking for if something was supported by Tcl would be a valid request.

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff I'll probably have to read more about Tcl to figure this one out.  I use the Linux package provided Tcl and expect and the only help I found was man pages on tclsh and expect themselves.  Nothing that dig deeper and can be queried, like pydoc I mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked the question this way instead: 'In Tcl, how to dynamically get documentation on a Tcl command or library command'?

Comment: I didn't say you were asking for opinion.  What part of *recommend **or find*** isn't clear? You're asking about **finding** a tool, which makes your post off-topic here, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: The Tclx package includes a `help` command. However, Tcl commands don't currently natively hold some sort of easily accessible help metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a tclsh prompt, you can try:

```
tclsh>  man lappend
```

On my system, (Linux w/ tcsh shell) this opened up the man page for lappend in a pager program (less, more, most).  This is really for interactive use, I suppose, and I'm not sure how you would integrate this into another tool, like your editor.

Comment: This is exactly what Ii was looking for! Thanks for recognizing the question for what it was.  As for the editor I'm using Emacs so I'll just pass it to a sub-shell that uses tcsh with the man command.

Comment: I think it's also possible to setup man to be able to open the Tcl man pages directly.  On your system do you know where the Tcl man pages are stored?

Comment: Use `man --path lappend` to return the path of the man page for lappend, for example.
Be aware that this file does not look exactly the same as when you display the contents with `man`.   
You can add to the MANPATH environment variable to tell `man` to use man pages in additional locations.   

I found man pages in many places.  /usr/share/man had a lot.   The man directory in my tcl installed location too.

Comment: Indeed. And by installing tcl-doc in Linux, the man pages get installed in the 3tcl section.  So to get the map page for lappend you can use ``man lappend`` to show it because it does not clash with anything else,  but to see help on string several pages on various sections are available.  One can use ``man -a string`` to show each one in sequence, but you can also use ``man 3tcl string`` to get to it directly.  And to see where that is location use ``man -w 3tcl string``.    The man ``-w``  (--path) and ``-W`` switch are quite useful.  I should just have asked for 'how to get Tcl help'.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get time to update my question.